# Java String to byte conversion issue

Tags: java, string, arrays, ascii

I have some test code which is not working as I expect, after reviewing various sites and specifications I still cannot figure out what is happening.

Here is my test code:

```
byte[] b = new byte[8];
b[0] = (byte)0x72;
b[1] = (byte)0x3A;
b[2] = (byte)0x60;
b[3] = (byte)0x01;
b[4] = (byte)0x0E;
b[5] = (byte)0x10;
b[6] = (byte)0x8A;
b[7] = (byte)0x11;
String bitmapStr = new String(b);
try {
    b = bitmapStr.getBytes("US-ASCII");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("DEBUG: bitmapStr = \"" +bitmapStr + "\"");
for (int i=0; i<=7; i++) {
    int byte1 = b[i];
    System.out.println("byte"+i + ": " + Integer.toHexString(byte1));
}
```

When I run the program I get the following in the console output:

```
DEBUG: bitmapStr = "r:`�"
byte0: 72
byte1: 3a
byte2: 60
byte3: 1
byte4: e
byte5: 10
byte6: 3f
byte7: 11
```

See how byte6 i.e. b[6] from my byte array outputs 0x3F, but it should be 0x8A.

Any ideas why?

By the way, if I use UTF-8 encoding I get an even more funky output (although ASCII is correct).

UTF-8 String encoding output:

```
byte0: 72
byte1: 3a
byte2: 60
byte3: 1
byte4: e
byte5: 10
byte6: ffffffef
byte7: ffffffbf
```

Comment: What text character is 0x8A supposed to represent, and in what encoding?  It's not ASCII, as previously stated here, and it does not appear to be ISO-8859-1 either. http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/latin1.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions from Rahul and irreputabe I figured it out:

When I changed to UTF-16LE / ISO-8859-1 encoding, byte6 was output as: "ffffff8a", then I realised I was performing a type conversion from byte to int here:

```
int byte1 = b[i];
```

So I just added:

```
int byte1 = b[i] & 0xFF;
```

for the correct result.

Answer (score 5):

Try another form of the String constructor:

```
String bitmapStr = new String(b,"ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: This doesn't work - I still get an odd result in byte 6.  8A is of course the only byte value where the most significant bit is set, so I assume the sign is affecting the conversion.

Comment: Updated my answer per your findings. Thanks.

Comment: No matter what kind of constructor he uses, he is casting a value as a byte which is outside of the byte range.  Even if you use the constructor from this answer, you end up with a negative value because of the byte cast.

Comment: Also, I don't think 0x8A is a valid character in ISO-8859-1. http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/latin1.gif

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this to change a string to byte:-

```
  String source = "2675326";
 byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
```

or change your code to:-

```
 String bitmapStr = new String(b,"US-ASCII");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing hexadecimal become byte ( 8 bits ). This is called casting and you cannot do that. You notice that all values have a good output `except when 0xYZ where Y >=8 !`
do not use casting unless you're sure you're not gonna lose information.

Comment: Err, what? Hexadecimal is simply another representation of the data, of course it's valid to cast from hex to byte, they are a different representation of the same thing!  When Y>=8 issues occur because ASCII encoding supports up to 7 bits, (the 7th bit is 0x80).